# Java getter vs Kotlin getter - any difference?

Tags: java, kotlin

Lets have these two getters in Kotlin:

```kotlin
data class Foo(var id: String){
  val reference get() = Reference("Patient/$id")
}
```

```kotlin
data class Foo(var id: String){
  fun getReference(){ return Reference("Patient/$id") }
}
```

Does the first one have some performance cons? I like it more, but I am not sure if they are built into same bytecode, or the first one adds more things, because I am basically delaring new variable and not just method.

Comment: You could use the Java decompiler (`javap`) to look at the generated bytecodes.

Comment: This looks like a premature optimization.  If there is any difference in performance (after the code has been compiled to native code) it is likely be a couple of machine instructions, and not significant to the overall performance of your application.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, they are equivalent behind the scenes (but obviously, you need different syntax for using the property vs. the method). Specifically, Kotlin will generate a backing field if any of the accessors use the [`field` identifier](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html#backing-fields), and the autogenerated `get` and `set` accessors do use `field`. So in order to avoid a backing field, you need to supply your own `get` accessor and (in the case of a `var` property) a `set` accessor, and none of them must use `field`.

Whether a property has a backing field or not, reading the property turns into a method call to `get()` behind the scenes, and if it's a `var`, assigning to the property turns into a method call to `set()`.

Note that it's possible to get into weird situations with `var` if your accessors are inconsistent: `var foo: Int = 3; get() = 42` will always return 42 when you read it, irrespective of the initial value and whatever you might assign to it, because you will get an autogenerated backing field since you omitted the setter, and that's what the autogenerated setter will set.

Using properties instead of Java-style getter/setter methods is strongly preferred in Kotlin.

(Thanks to @AlexeyRomanov for pointing out the specific rules.)

Comment: Mmm. I think the only significant difference is that the first version lets you call the getter with `myFoo.reference`, while the second has to look like `myFoo.getReference()`. But they both compile to pretty much the same.

Comment: "when you declare a get() accessor for a property, no backing field will be generated" This isn't sufficient: 1. The accessor must not use `field` keyword; 2. If the property is a `var`, the `set()` accessor also must not use `field` (and the default one does).

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov: Thank you - I have incorporated this into my answer.

Comment: "(that's basically how you override Kotlin's default behavior and say that you do want a backing field even though you have supplied the accessors)" I still would not phrase it like that :) The behavior is simply: 1. if accessors use `field`, the compiler creates a backing field, if not, not. 2. the default `get` and `set` accessors both use `field`.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov: Fair enough - I have rewritten my answer again.